# Des expressions pour dire plus que « cela suggère », mais moins que « c’est sûr »

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Je cherche des formulations qui rentreraient dans cette phrase :

> Tout cela [suggère avec une haute probabilité] que ce n’est pas ceci
>   qui se passe, mais cela.

Des idées:

> … laisse penser [avec une certaine certitude] [sans trop de risque]
>
> ... suggère plutôt fortement. (Ma favorite, mais pas sûr que ça se dise !)

Et vous, laquelle (ou lesquelles) préférez-vous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne préfère aucune des possibilités suivantes mais elles sont toutes acceptables selon mon jugement. Il faut dire que la liste que je fournit peut être rallongée : ce n'est qu'une question de chercher plus longtemps, d'y penser un moment, si on est familier avec la langue française.

- tend à confirmer
- prouve presque indéniablement
- apporte la quasi confirmation
- pointe à la quasi certitude
- rend plus que probable
- contribue à nous assurer
- étaye fortement la supposition
- nous assure pratiquement sans aucun doute
- nous amène à croire
- indique presque indubitablement
- montre assez clairement

D'après la définition du TLFi, on pourrait penser qu'il ne devrait pas y avoir de raison pour ne pas utiliser « suggère fortement », puisqu'il est question d'intensité;

> B.− [Adv. de quantité ou d'intensité] 
>   1. [Modifiant un verbe ou une loc. verb.] Beaucoup, dans des proportions importantes. Rougir fortement; compromettre fortement; contribuer fortement à; abaisser, accroître, diminuer fortement.

Je ne suis pas sûr non plus que les deux concepts soit parfaitement compatibles et il me semble qu'il serait peut être préférable de dire quelque chose comme « suggère vivement ». Mais lorsque l'on se penche sur le sens de ce dernier adverbe on trouve la définition ci-après;

> 1. D'une manière intense, qui affecte profondément la sensibilité. Synon. fortement, profondément.Être vivement ému, troublé. Celui qui a moins de plaisirs les sent plus vivement

Comment: Excellent, merci beaucoup!