# Des synonymes de "cela soulève la question"

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Je ne trouve que ça:

- [tout cela] force/pousse à se demander.../à se poser la question.../à s'interroger sur...
- [tout cela] soulève la question...

En voyez-vous d'autres?

PS: à ne pas confondre avec cette autre question: [Des expressions pour dire plus que « cela suggère », mais moins que « c’est sûr »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32849/des-expressions-pour-dire-plus-que-cela-sugg%C3%A8re-mais-moins-que-c-est-s%C3%BBr)

Comment: It will be difficult to answer if you don't  clarify how you are using the controversial "beg the question". Aren't you confusing "begging the question" with  "eliciting the question" or "raising the question"? Can you clarify?  https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/beg-the-question; https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/begs-the-question; https://grammarist.com/usage/begging-the-question-usage/; http://begthequestion.info/

Comment: You are right, I don't know the differences of these expressions (so I removed it from my question).

Comment: But (off topic now) you said `Aren't you confusing "begging the question" with "eliciting the question"` but following your link I see in the first sentence: `Begging the question means "to elicit a specific question[...]"`.

Comment: Have you read it all?  If I said controversial it is for a reason.  I can read : "To beg the question does not mean "to raise the question."" or  "There are plenty of phrases writers can use when they mean "makes me wonder" or "raises the question." There's no hole in the English language that needs to be filled, so there's no reason to use begs the question improperly."  etc.That is why I asked you to clarify." What sense were you giving to "beg the question"?

Comment: @None I find your argumentation rather conservative and your goal to correct it rather useless. I believe a language does no follow the rules/conventions nor logic but simply the way the majority of (native?) people speak. What is "improper" in my opinion is to panic when things change/evolve.

Comment: If there are several uses to a word/phrase and you don't precise what use you are making of it, how do you want people to help you? I'm the first here to always say language evolves, but we're not in your head to make a guess and know how you are using the word. You should really stop misquoting me and read properly what people say, when quoting (using quotes:" ") I am just [quoting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quote#Verb), not giving an opinion.

Comment: Cela soulève la question de x: That raises the issue of x